# How to format text in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, text

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df

id  Description
1   2694 A&W #5530 MONTREAL QC
2   ahi DOLLARAMA # 45 MONTREAL QC
3   PC - PAYMENT FROM - *****11*22
```

I want to format this dataframe, so that the columns `df["Description"]` doesn't have `#`, `-`, `*` or `numbers` like:

```
id  Description

1   A&W MONTREAL QC
2   ahi DOLLARAMA MONTREAL QC
3   PC PAYMENT FROM
```

I tried using the python module re. But I am getting it all wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the regular expression like this:

```
df.Description = df.Description.str.replace(r'[\d#\-\*]', '')
```

This gives

```
0               A&W  MONTREAL QC
1    ahi DOLLARAMA   MONTREAL QC
2             PC  PAYMENT FROM  
Name: foo, dtype: object
```

Comment: The problem is, this doesn't account for numbers at the beginning of lines.

Comment: @Graham Why do you think so? It works by me on the example, I think.

Comment: Huh. I probably misunderstand Panda dataframes.

Comment: I still think that the OP wanted trailing spaces removed based on their example, so [`df.Description = df.Description.str.replace(r'[-#*\d]+ ?, '')`](https://regex101.com/r/2I4ZmD/2/) may be better suited for the OP's desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment (and the upvote) Graham (BTW, I don't think you should have erased yours). For trailing whitespaces, I personally would continue the chain with `.str.rstrip()`, but I see your point as well.

Comment: I deleted mine because it was not specific to the question actually being asked, to the extent that it actually performed erroneously when given certain input. I could have edited my answer, but your answer does a perfect job of accomplishing exactly what the OP (and anyone who I'd imagine would stumble on this question) are looking for.

Comment: @AmiTavory: No need to escape everything just because it is within a character class, `[-\d#*]` will equally work (note the `-` right at the beginning). `*` has no special meaning within a character class. +1 for `.str.replace()`.

Comment: Add `df.Description.str.split().str.join(' ') ` to get rid of extra whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas `.apply` and `re.sub` to remove `[^A-Z ]+`, i.e.:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
test = ['2694 A&W #5530 MONTREAL QC', 'ahi DOLLARAMA # 45 MONTREAL QC', 'PC - PAYMENT FROM - *****11*22']

def change_me(content):
    content =  re.sub(r"[^A-Z ]+", "", content, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
    return re.sub(r"[ ]{2,}", " ", content, 0, re.IGNORECASE)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Desc':test})
df.Desc = df.Desc.apply(change_me)
```

---

```
                        Desc
0             AW MONTREAL QC
1  ahi DOLLARAMA MONTREAL QC
2            PC PAYMENT FROM
```

---

[Regex Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/XQa0PY/3)

---

PS:
Please read  @ami's comment, `.str.replace()` is the appropriate function for this kind of task.

Comment: This sort of redundant `apply` is very much discouraged in Pandas. It is exactly why there are operations like the `.str` ones.